NTAG-5 LINK (BY NXP) antenna design
I want to use a flex antenna with the NTAG5-LINK (NTP5332) by NXP. NXP has designs for Class 4,5 and 6 antennas (https://www.nxp.com/products/no-longer-manufactured/ntag-ic-iplus-i-flex-kit-containing-additional-flex-antennas:OM5569-NT322F). I was wondering if I can directly use those designs with the NTAG 5 link without making any changes to the shape and size of the antenna.
I do not have experience with antenna design so I would like to use an existing design with the NTAG 5 link. My requirements is that the antenna needs to be small (Class 6 antenna size should suffice) So, if I could use the PCB design file of class 6 antenna in combination with the NTAG 5  it would be good for me.
Could you please tell me if it is possible?
